# Laravel image uploaded not appearing in mySQL database

Tags: php, laravel, forms, image

I've tried uploaded an image, but the only thing that is saved is picture inside the local folder. I've tried many ways such as using the save method, but everything is not working for me.
It's appearing blank in the database table. When I dd($request0>all()), the name of the file did appeared, but after I dd($funds). Somehow the image attribute is gone.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate funds form data
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|unique:funds|min:5|max:100',
            'content' => 'required|string|min:5|max:2000',
            'image' => 'required|image|max:2048',
        ]);

        $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
        $validated['image'] = $request->image->storeAs('images', $filename, 'public');

        // Create slug from title
        $validated['slug'] = Str::slug($validated['title'], '-');

        // Create and save funds with validated data
        $funds = Fund::create($validated);

        // Redirect the user to the created funds with a success notification
        return redirect(route('funds.index', [$funds->slug]))->with('success', 'Post created!');
    }
```

**Blade**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('funds.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          @csrf
          @include('partials.errors')

          <div class="field">
              <label class="label">Image</label>
                 <div class="control">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                        <img src="#" alt="image" id="img"
                              style="max-width:150px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 60%;">
                           <input type="file" id="upload" name="image">
                    </div>
                 </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
               <div class="control">
                     <button type="submit" class="button is-link is- 
                       outlined">Publish</button>
               </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the table's column that's supposed to store the image is of the `binary` data type, it'll never show up in the database.

You didn't show your table's schema, so I can only guess here. If the image is being uploaded and stored to your storage directory, I recommend you save the file path to the database after it's done uploading (it's a string). Alternatively, you could just  `base64_encode` the image and store it on that column, so that it can be displayed with an `<img>` element later.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem) part of the official documentation.

> $path = Storage::disk('public')->put($fileName, $path);

Then save the $path value in database for the imagePath field.

You can specify drive. Public is the one accessible to all users once you run php artisan storage:link command in your terminal. Local disk is everything in private "/storage/app/private/.....".

Also for the slugs have a look at at this [package](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable). It will generate slugs automatically if you install and configure it properly in your specific models.